# Efficient method for generating these sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Problem:** 
I need to generate the following sequence. I have the order of the matrix as input.

**Example:**
I need to generate the sequence of position of its elements.

```
 (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) ->for order 2
 (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2) -> for order 3.
```

I need to have function which does this for me. When I call this function it should calculate for me on the fly. I don't want to store the sequence in the memory.

Eg:

```
first_call - > return value (0,0)
second_call to function - > return value ( 0,1)
...and so on...
```

You can store these values in some global variables.

**PS:**
The function has to be thread-safe as the application is multi-threaded. I know this condition doesn't make difference. Just wanted to convey the entire problem.

**Precision:**
I have tried my solution but I think its in efficient. I am looking for an efficient method to do that. You can just mention the steps. I don't need implementation in any particular language. Please let me know if more info is required for the question.

Comment: **I dont want to store the sequence in the memory**. Eg: first_call - > return value (0,0) second_call to function - > return value ( 0,1)...and so on... **You can store these values in some global variables.** -- what?

Comment: IVIad....I appreciate for your effort...I got my solution...thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a global variable to store the number of times you have called the function. Call it `t`. If order is `order`, then

f = (`t` div `order`, `t` mod `order`)

Where `div` is the integer division (e.g. 5 `div` 3 = 1) and `mod` is the modulus (i.e. remainder of the division). (e.g. 5 `mod` 3 = 2).

So in Java for example:

```
public class MyCounter {

    private static int t = 0;

    public static int[] myFunction(int order) {
        return new int[] { t / order , t++ % order };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int order = 3;
        for(int i=0; i<order*order; i++) {
            int[] k = myFunction(order);            
            System.out.println("("+k[0]+", "+k[1]+")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mprivat ....excellent...Thanks!!!..got your response in less than 5 mins....stackoverflow rocks!!

Comment: stackoverflow rocks because of users who help each other. Now that you've gotten your answer, don't forget to come back and scan other questions you may know the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MATRIX_ORDER 3

void NextPosition(int aIndex, int& aRow, int& aColumn)
{
    if (aColumn == MATRIX_ORDER - 1)
    {
        aRow++;
        aColumn = 0;
    } else {
        aColumn++;
    }
}


void SomeFunction()
{
    int index = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int column = -1;

    while (index < (MATRIX_ORDER * MATRIX_ORDER))
    {
        NextPosition(index, row, column);
        printf("index: %d, row: %d, column: %d\n", index, row, column);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
index: 0, row: 0, column: 0
index: 1, row: 0, column: 1
index: 2, row: 0, column: 2
index: 3, row: 1, column: 0
index: 4, row: 1, column: 1
index: 5, row: 1, column: 2
index: 6, row: 2, column: 0
index: 7, row: 2, column: 1
index: 8, row: 2, column: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution using a generator:

```
def sequence_gen(order=2):
    for i in range(order*order):
        yield divmod(i, order)


for val in sequence_gen(2):
    print(val)

#(0, 0)
#(0, 1)
#(1, 0)
#(1, 1)

for val in sequence_gen(3):
    print(val)

#(0, 0)
#(0, 1)
#(0, 2)
#(1, 0)
#(1, 1)
#(1, 2)
#(2, 0)
#(2, 1)
#(2, 2)
```